# MongoDB extremely slow performance when filtering or sorting on a non indexed field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

MongoDB is running `find()` operations very slow when I `sort` or `search` on `non-indexed` fields. When there is not sorting or searching on these fields or this operations are made on `indexed` fields the `query` runs very fast. My test database has only 650k documents (which is not very much), but the final database will have 50 million documents growing 30k/day.

This is a query which runs fast (less than 1s), only filtering on indexed fields:

```
.find({
    tipo_doc: 'nfe', //indexed field
    id_empresa: 7 //indexed field
},
{
    sort: {'data_requisicao': -1}, //indexed field
    limit: 3000
});
```

And this is a query which runs very slow (30s or more):

```
.find({
        tipo_doc: 'nfe', //indexed field
        id_empresa: 7, //indexed field
        'transportador.xNome': 'A commom name' //not indexed field
    },
    {
        sort: {'emitente.enderEmit.UF': -1}, //not indexed field
        limit: 3000
    });
```

Here's a `JSON` document example: https://pastebin.com/1EeaL9VL

I've made a lot of researchs but nothing seems to work here.. I am doing something wrong to get this poor performance?

**EDIT:**

As I said in my comment, this data will be shown on a `HTML` `table`, and every `column` will be searchable and sortable, so I assume I can't create an `index` on every column..

Comment: If any of the key in the filter criteria or in sort criteria is not indexed then the query will do collscan. You do have index on `transportador.xNome` and `emitente.enderEmit.UF` to be used your query for indexing.

Comment: @Ashh The problem is I'll show this data on a HTML table, and every column is searchable and sortable.. I think I would have a lot of other problems if I create an index in every column.. Do you have any suggestions of what can I do in this case?